# How to join two columns into a one column of vectors/lists in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
|   X   |   Y   |
|-------|-------|
|   x1  |   y1  |
|   x2  |   y2  |
|   x3  |   y3  |
|  ...  |  ...  |
| x1000 | y1000 |
```

How can I make a third column that will consist of vectors/lists containing accessible values grabbed from the first two?

```
|   X   |   Y   |         Z        |
|-------|-------|------------------|
|   x1  |   y1  |     c(x1,y1)     |  
|   x2  |   y2  |     c(x2,y2)     |
|   x3  |   y3  |     c(x3,y3)     |
|  ...  |  ...  |        ...       |
| x1000 | y1000 |  c(x1000,y1000)  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to concatenate the elements in 'X', 'Y' into a `vector` and return a `list` with `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Z = map2(X, Y, c))
```

Or another option is to `paste` into a string

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Z = str_c(X, Y, sep=","))
```

---

Or with `Map` from `base R`

```
df1$Z <- Map(c, df1$X, df1$Y)
```

Comment: Thanks but somehow all I get in Z are vectors like c(2, 2), c(3, 3), c(38, 38) etc. No matter which option I try. How can I access the real values? Because `df$Z[1]` returns  `2 2`.

Comment: @tnpchik  Can you type `c(2, 2)` on the console and see what it returns?  It is a vector, and just like that each element of `Z` is a vector

Comment: > c(2, 2)
[1] 2 2

Comment: @tnpchlk  Isn't that `df$Z[[1]]` returns

Comment: Yup, but where did those values come from? I wanted to have c(myStringFromX, myStringFromY) and not c(2,2).

Comment: @tnpchik  According to your expected, you want to create a vector from each row of the dataset.  This is doing that and placing it in a `list`.  `map2` or `Map` combines each corresponding element of 'X', 'Y' into  vector element in a `list`

Comment: Well it seems to do exactly what you say, but still values in each vector in the newly created column are not strings from columns X and Y but some random-looking numbers. (they almost correspond to the row number they're in. but only almost...)

Comment: @tnpchlk  Hmm.  Got the issue.  You have `factor` columns and by concatenating it gets coerced to integer storage values.  You can do `df1 %>% mutate(Z = map2(as.character(X), as.character(Y), c))`