# How to join 3 columns (strings) into a one column (list of strings) in R? (excluding NA)

Tags: r

I have the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434861/how-to-join-two-columns-into-a-one-column-of-vectors-lists-in-r/73966220#73966220), but I have 3 columns (type `chr`) which I want to combine as one column Z which is a list of the other 3 strings.

```
|   X   |   Y   |  R     |         Z              |
|-------|-------|--------|------------------------|
|   x1  |   y1  |   r1   |     c(x1,y1, r1)       |  
|   x2  |   y2  |   r2   |     c(x2,y2, r2)       |
|   x3  |   y3  |   NA   |     c(x3,y3)           |
|  ...  |  ...  |   ...  |        ...             |
| x1000 | y1000 | r1000  |  c(x1000,y1000, r1000) |
```

The base `Map(f, ...)` function worked for me:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~X,    ~Y,    ~R,
  "x1",  "y1", "r1",
  "x2",  "y2", "r2",
  "x3",  "y3", NA,
)

df$Z <-  Map(c, df$X, df$Y, df$R)

class(df$Z) # [1] "list"

df$Z[3] # [1] "x3" "y3" NA
```

Now I need to **deal with NA which I do NOT want in Z**. Basically, I need `df$Z[3]` to be `c(x3,y3)` NOT `c(x3,y3, NA)`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Z = pmap(across(everything()), ~ na.omit(c(...))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `NA` values after `c()`oncatenating:

```
Map(\(...) {o <- c(...); o[!is.na(o)]}, df$X, df$Y, df$R)
#$x1
#[1] "x1" "y1" "r1"
#
#$x2
#[1] "x2" "y2" "r2"
#
#$x3
#[1] "x3" "y3"
```

Or without writing out each variable in `df`:

```
do.call(Map, c(\(...) {o <- c(...); o[!is.na(o)]}, unname(df)))
```

Comment: OK, this works as well, but it wasn't exactly what I was asking, bc I don't want to touch the original df cols, only drop NA in the output col (Z).  Also I had not seen the syntax `\(...)`  and it is a bit obscure for me...

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to remove the NA value? If so, this dplyr approach should work:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(Z))
```

If you need to replace it with an empty string, try this:

```
df$Z[is.na(df$Z)] <- ""
```

Comment: No, this doesn't do the job, because `length(df$Z[[3]])`  is still 3, and I want it to go down to 2